How can I map the result of a custom query to a DTO in Spring Boot?
I am trying to retrieve a dataset from Neo4j making use of a custom query and map the data with a DTO. The problem is that I am trying to retrieve information from different nodes that are related, one of them as a list, and that list does not map to the results. In Neo4j Workspace (on the web) the information is retrieved correctly, but in Spring Boot it does not map.
I am using this query to retrieve the information:
MATCH (person:Person) WHERE toLower(person.fullname) =~ toLower("Fullname")
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:HAS]->(event:Event) WHERE (person)-[:HAS]->(event)
WITH event, person
RETURN person, COLLECT(DISTINCT event{.*}) as events

From Neo4j Workspace the information is correct:
Example
But the data received shows that the Events list has not been mapped.
[
    {
        "id": "00000000",
        "name": "Name",
        "fullname": "Fullname",
        "sex": "Masculino",
        "first_surname": "Surname",
        "second_surname": "Surname",
        "events": []
    }
]

The result should be as follows:
[
    {
        "id": "00000000",
        "name": "Name",
        "fullname": "Fullname",
        "sex": "Masculino",
        "first_surname": "Surname",
        "second_surname": "Surname",
        "events": [{
                    id:"0000000",
                    type:"type",
                    place:"Some place",
                    date:1900-01-01
        }]
    }
]

The DTO classes I am using are as follows:
PersonDTO.java
@Data
public class PersonDTO {
    
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String firstSurname;
    private String secondSurname;
    private String fullname;
    private String sex;

    private List<EventDTO> events;

}

EventDTO.java
@Data
public class EventDTO {

    private String id;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String place;
    private String type;

}

The repository looks like this:
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person,String> {
    
    @Query("MATCH (person:Person) WHERE toLower(person.fullname) =~ toLower($fullname)\n"
    + "OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:HAS]->(event:Event) WHERE (person)-[:HAS]->(event)\n"
    + "WITH event, person\n"
    + "RETURN person, COLLECT(DISTINCT event{.*}) as events")
    List<PersonDTO> findByFullname(@Param("fullname") String fullname);

}

That's all...!
Thanks.

If you are sure that your events data is getting retrieved properly you can try mapstruct.
This will help you to map your custom fields from entity to DTO.
You just need to define methods, mapstruct will give implementation according to the method parameter types and return types you provide.
